# event.touches fallback in IE 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an app which is using event.touches in the MSPointerDown(touchstart in other browsers) event handler which is not working in IE 10. Any fallback?

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Lauke wrote an excellent article on [detecting touch](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/) which also covers MS weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use

```
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
  // Pointer events are supported.
}
```

to handle IE10 specific interaction.
[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx) is an extensive doc about Touch input in IE10.

```
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
  // IE10 supports this
  this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", eventHandlerName, false);
}
// for other browsers
this.element.addEventListener("touchstart", eventHandlerName, false);
```

IE10 should support MSPointerDown, the fallback is after for the browsers who don't support Pointer interaction.